# how to make pretty url of two different pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two pages in same directory like:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=about
www.example.com/page.php?var=abc
```

I want it as like:

```
www.example.com/about
www.example.com/var/abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^var/([^/]+) page.php?var=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for help. but when i use www.example.com/var/abc then all the urls of css and js takes after www.example.com/var/
How can i resolve it

Comment: Try adding a `/` in front of your path. like `href="/path/to/style.css"` or use full path. `href="http://yoursite.com/path/to/style.css"` It's best to use absolute paths when doing rewrites to prevent such a thing.